# Error on Expo React Native trying to start on web, how can i fix it?

Tags: react-native, expo

Basically, when I create a new expo project and use npm run web it throws me this error and I can't find the solution, please help, thanks

it does works to open it with android, the problem is only running on web

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at X:\DataYProgramas\ReactJS\expo4\openty\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of node.js you using, because for me is not working on latest(18.12.1) but working on 16.18.1, but on version 16.18.1 not working on ios

Comment: My nodejs version is 18.12.1 still dont know how to fix it :(

Comment: I don 't know why but on 18.12.1 is not working on web.

Comment: Hi Filip. You made a great job in asking for more details. However this should rather be done in a comment to the question and not as an answer in StackOverflow. The answer should be like: I have version xxx and the solution for that version is xxxx